# ImportError with feather/pyarrow

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, feather

I am getting an error when running `import feather`:

```
---> 28 from pyarrow.lib import cpu_count, set_cpu_count
     29 from pyarrow.lib import (null, bool_,
     30                          int8, int16, int32, int64,
ImportError: cannot import name 'cpu_count'
```

Anyone know how to fix this? I have `pyarrow` installed and up to date, and from what I can tell `cpu_count` isn't a package I can install.

Comment: have you tried this line directly in a terminal ? is there something before this line that could block the import  ?

Comment: @PRMoureu: I did try it in the terminal as well. I ended up deleting the package and reinstalling it and that ended up working... Not sure what the exact solution was though.

Comment: I'm having this issue too - deleting package and reinstalling with pip didn't resolve issue for me

Comment: Only seeing this issue in python 2.7.  `import pyarrow` works fine on my python 3.6 installation.

Comment: @andrew: Try doing your install with `conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow` instead of pip. That's what worked for me. I deleted the entire pyarrow folder from the Anaconda packages directory.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Found this which appears to be similar - exception generated on the same line of pyarrow. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1554

Answer (score 0):

This is because Python 2.X does not have `cpu_count()` function in OS module. But python3 has cpu_count() in its OS module. I recommend you to use either python3 or patch the file with `from multiprocessing import cpu_count`